# "violates our Terms of Service" when publishing Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

When I go to publish my form it says "It appears that this form violates our Terms of Service. Please return to the Build page and revise your form and try again." But it does not give me a reason nor does it tell me what to revise.

What could this issue be?

Answer (score 1):

Please fill out the Cognito Forms Request Help with your contact information so we can trace what might be triggering the security flag on your form.
Here is that link

https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/